# Is there any verse to have nice wife?

Tags: belief, mantras, women

Many of my friends married recently and all of them were either unhappy or divorced. I was wondering if there is any mantra or verse that ask god to provide very nice wife.

Is there any verse to have nice wife?

Comment: Unhappy marriage life is mainly due to bad Karmas in previous life(s).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From Markendya Purana there is Argalastrotram created by Vishnu sage. There is a verse in that. Taken from Durga saptashati of Markandeya Purana .

> पत्नीं मनोरमाम देहि मनोवृत्तानुसारिणिम 
>  तारिणीमदुर्गसंसारसागरस्य
>   कुलोद्भवाम
>
> patnim manoramaam dehi manovrittanusarineem 
> taarineem durgasansar sagarasye kulodbhavaam
>
> Give me a wife in harmony with my mind; that makes the life journey easier for me.

This verse is chanted in time of Pratah(6-9 AM) and sayam (6-9 PM). And the direction of sitting should be north.

Taken from Durga saptashati of Markandeya Purana

Comment: Where in the Markandeya Purana is this verse?

Comment: It is either in Vishnu Purana or Markendya Purana. Taken from Durga saptashati of Markandeya Purana

Comment: I think this mantra should be chanted 140000 times.

Answer (score 2):

GODDESS DURGA MANTRA FOR ATTAINMENT OF A GOOD WIFE.

Marriage is a sacred union that binds two individuals. It ties them legally and emotionally. It is the sacred bond for the whole life. So every boy longs for a good wife. The regular and continuous chant of the following mantra by the boy helps him get the good wife of his choice.

Process of Mantra Jap:-
After getting fresh from daily routine sit on a rug facing east or north in a separate room or at any suitable place. Keep a framed picture of Devi Durga in front of you. Close your eyes and meditate on Devi Durga feeling that she is present everywhere. She is the symbol of power and energy. She is known as the universal mother. She has the power  to fulfill the desires of a person who has full faith in her. I bow to that mother, I bow to Devi Durga, I bow to Shakti.
After this feeling and prayer, repeat (Jap or chant) the following Mantra at least 324 times (three Malas) or 540 times (five Malas). The more Jap you do, the better it is. For desired result the mantra should be recited for 125000 (one lac twenty five) times.

The Mantra is as follows:-

> 'Patneem Manoramaam Dehi Manovrittaanu Saarineem 
>  Taarineem Durg
>   Sansaar Saagarasya Kulodbhavaam.'
>
> 'पत्नीं  मनोरमां देहि मनोवृतानु सारिणीम ! 
>  तारिणीम  दुर्ग संसार 
>   सागरस्य  कुलोद्भवाम !!,

When the Jap is over do not leave the place immediately. After the mantra Jap sit very quietly, close your eyes and reflect upon the infinitive love of devi Durga. Have a feeling in your mind that Devi Durga has accepted your prayer. She is pouring her blessings upon you. She is giving you the boon of having a good wife. And also have the faith that you will certainly have a good wife with the grace of Devi Durga.
After it fold your hands and pay your respects to goddess Durga and leave the place of Pooja and commence your routine duties.

Source : http://www.astromuhurat.com/2012/10/6-remedy-durga-mantra.html?m=1

Comment: Your answer is simply a copy-paste from that page.

Comment: Does it matter? The copied text is for easier access.

Answer (score 1):

Mantras are chanted by receiving diksha for them. Find a guru who will offer you diksha of the mantra for good wife.

There is this website called GuruShakti, [GuruShakti web link sundar patni shabar mantra](https://www.gurushakti.org.in/130/sadhna/mantra-for-bride) they offer such dikshas. Have a look at it.

Comment: This looks like a link like answer. Can you add what is there in the link? Just in case, the link is dead, answer won't be invalid.